# Java moving number between stacks

Tags: java, stack

I have a question, about using Stack with Java.

Let's say I have three stacks

```
Stack<Integer> stack1 = new Stack<Integer>();
Stack<Integer> stack2 = new Stack<Integer>();
Stack<Integer> stack3 = new Stack<Integer>();

stack1.push(10);
stack1.push(5);
stack1.push(25);
stack1.push(2);
stack1.push(100);
```

I want these numbers in order from high to low in stack3.
So stack3 likes like 100, 25, 10, 5, 2

What would be the best method of moving the number between the stacks?

Comment: Are you only allowed to use the stacks? Can you have temporary storage? And are these the only numbers you care about, or are you going for a generic solution?

Answer (score 3):

Due to some bad design decisions in Java, it is possible to make `Collections.sort(stack1)` and then simply pop out of the first stack and push into the 2nd.

But note that since Java 6 it is preferable to use `ArrayDeque` (or another `Deque`) instead of `Stack`. With a stack that is not a `List`, the sequence would be:

1. Take them all out of the first stack (in a `List` or an array)
2. Sort them (`Collections.sort(..)` or `Arrays.sort(..)`)
3. Push them in order into the other stack

But these all java "hacks". If it is a homework problem it is more likely that they want you to implement something like the "Towers of Hanoi" problem, as noted by smas.

Comment: The numbers be any number, and I can use a temp stack.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is called: the Tower of Hanoi problem, try find code/description for this in wikipedia/google.

Comment: No, it is not. In the Hanoi problem, the elements of any stack are always sorted. In Billy's problem, the elements are initially unsorted, and the goal is to sort them using only the stacks.

Comment: I guess it doesn't matter that the elements are unsorted initially. The same algorithm will works

Answer (score 0):

Re-phrasing Bozho's answer:

```
    Stack<Integer> stack3 = new Stack<Integer>();
    Integer[] arr = stack.toArray(new Integer[stack.size()]);
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    stack3.addAll(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

Comment: I deliberately did not include code. It's likely a homework, and students should learn to write code :)